# Error parsing XML with XStream and Xalan

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xstream

I am parsing XML with the XStream 1.3 API and the Xalan API. There is some XML which is huge for which I am getting the following exception. Can you please advise how to overcome this. Do I need to increase the Java heap space?

```
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMException: No more DTM IDs are availablecom.rbsfm.ice.ioa.exception.IOARuntimeException: ERROR: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMException: No more DTM IDs are available
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform
```

Comment: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-N10340 suggests it is a problem solved by using a more recent version of Xalan. I would also consider to try Saxon 9 instead of Xalan as that way you can use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Matin so shall I go for latest version of xalan , i am using jdk 1.5 and if yes tan which version of xalan please advise

Comment: You will have to try which version of Xalan works with your JDK and hopefully does not expose the problem, their web site is http://xalan.apache.org/.