# getting error while parsing huge xml through transformation

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

I am using xalan api for my xsl transformations and finally getting xml , now i got one xml which was very huge and it was giving the below exception mention the below url also..

[Error parsing XML with XStream and Xalan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365391/error-parsing-xml-with-xstream-and-xalan)

but as now I have upgraded the xalan api to 2.7 now but still now i am getting the below error..

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serializer/ExtendedContentHandler
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.XSLTSchema.build(XSLTSchema.java:325)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.XSLTSchema.<init>(XSLTSchema.java:72)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.StylesheetHandler.<init>(StylesheetHandler.java:1290)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplatesHandler(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:376)
```

Comment: Sounds like a version mismatch happening somewhere. What're you using to manage dependencies?

Comment: @CliveEvans by version mismatch i didnt get while i am using xalan 1.7 and jdk 1.5

Comment: XSLTSchema is in xalan. The ExtendedContenHandler appears to be in the xalan serializer jar.

Comment: @CliveEvans thanks for the explanation so what api should i upgrade i am using xalan 1.7 rite now with jdk 1.5 please advise